# Which is efficient to convert Columns to Rows in Spark Stack function or Unpivot Command on huge data?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, bigdata, databricks

Im working a PySpark script which has to process huge data (5 TB+) using some logic to convert columns to rows in a table.

Sample input data:

```
+-------+------+-----+------+----+
|Product|Canada|China|Mexico| USA|
+-------+------+-----+------+----+
| Orange|  null| 4000|  null|4000|
|  Beans|  null| 1500|  2000|1600|
| Banana|  2000|  400|  null|1000|
|Carrots|  2000| 1200|  null|1500|
```

Expected Output:

```
+-------+-------+-----+
|Product|Country|Total|
+-------+-------+-----+
| Orange|  China| 4000|
|  Beans|  China| 1500|
|  Beans| Mexico| 2000|
| Banana| Canada| 2000|
| Banana|  China|  400|
|Carrots| Canada| 2000|
|Carrots|  China| 1200|
+-------+-------+-----+
```

I found two approaches to achieve the same:

1. Using [Stack Function](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#stack) on DF
2. Using [UnPivot](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.4.1/sql-ref-syntax-qry-select-unpivot.html) on Spark SQL

**Question: Both result in the same output I want to understand which is efficient and optimal on huge data.**

Thanks

Comment: try on your data.